# How to change an attribute of a variable in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, variables, attributes

I'm struggeling with something basic and I can't seem to work it out.

The following works perfectly:

```
switch (url_param) {
    case '80':
        $('input[name=power][value=80]').prop('checked', true);
        break;
    case '90':
        $('input[name=power][value=90]').prop('checked', true);
        break;
    case '99':
        $('input[name=power][value=99]').prop('checked', true);
        break;
}
```

However, I have to interact with many different inputs on the page so I would like to store them into variables first, for example

```
$input_power = $('input[name=power]');
```

How can I achieve the same result, using a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to filter out the matched element.

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
var $input_power = $('input[name=power]');
switch (url_param) {
    case '80':
    case '90':
    case '99':
        $input_power.filter(function(){
            return parseInt(this.value, 10) == parseInt(url_param, 10);
        }).prop('checked', true);
        break;
}
```

In the above example I have improved the code and used `parseInt(str, radix)` for integer.

Answer (score 1):

Remove switch case statements and use only one line this

```
$('input[name=power][value='+ url_param +']').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: this indeed would work, however I do need the switches to check the values. In addition I have to use a variable for all inputs, as I'm using them multiple times in the code. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myInput = $('input[name=power][value=80]');
```

Somewhere later in your code:

```
$(myInput).prop('checked', true);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want to create a new variable for each new value...this was my problem in the first place. Thanks for answering nevertheless!